# Can C# Collection Initializers accept a lambda generator or only fixed values

Tags: c#, initializer

This is kind of a duplicate of [c#, using lambdas with collection initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402860/c-using-lambdas-with-collection-initialization), but its 13 odd years old and things have changed. Hopefully.

I'm writing a one off unit test, so I'm not looking for extension methods or something that requires lots of supporting code. I could probably have written the code in less time than this question takes, but now I'm curious and my Google-fu hasn't turned up anything useful/recent. A yes (and how)/no answer would suffice initially and reasons can follow later.

The MS docs on collection initializers indicate in one of their examples that you can use a method to return a single value. BUT, what about a collection instead? no mention. There is a (closed) 7 year old [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/963) for Roslyn which was never implemented, and now has dead links, that is similar to what I'm thinking.

How to do something like this *without* writing another function in the test class:

```
ClassA instanceA = new ClassA {
    MyListB = new List<ClassC>() { 
        () => { 
           List<ClassC> list = new List<ClassC>();
           for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
               list.add(new ClassC() {SomeProp = i});
           return list;
         }
    }
}
```

I suppose the extra nesting level is irrelevant for the question, it just matches my current structure.

I know I can write

```
List<ClassC> GetList() {
    List<ClassC> list = new List<ClassC>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       list.add(new ClassC() {SomeProp = i});
    return list;
}

ClassA instanceA = new ClassA {
    MyListB = GetList()
}
```

Just curious as to if there is a different (more lazy?) way?

I'm using VS2022, the test project is xUnit using .Net Core 6, and the system under test is a .Net 4.6.1 dll project. Language version ranges through the various projects. It's irritating, but I'm working on it, I'm a new starter to an established solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a collection initialiser is basically an array literal so using a method makes no sense. This should do what you want:

```cs
ClassA instanceA = new ClassA
                   {
                       MyListB = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                                           .Select(i => new ClassC {SomeProp = i})
                                           .ToList()
                   };
```